# org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: *hbm.xml not found

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

JBoss AS 7.0.1.Final, Hibernate 3.  We have a MySQL datasource.

I have mapping resources pointing to *hbm.xml files.  I get deployment errors that tell me 'resource: *hbm.xml not found', so entities are not being mapped correctly - this stack trace is due to the User.hbm.xml not being found,

```
14:44:34,654 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-9) HHH00042:Configuring from file: hibernate.cfg.xml
14:44:34,668 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver] (MSC service thread 1-9) HHH00223:Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:44:34,670 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-9) HHH00221:Reading mappings from resource: User.hbm.xml
14:44:34,697 SEVERE [com.mycompany.myapp.common.persistence.HibernateUtil] (MSC service thread 1-9) Initial SessionFactory lookup failed.: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: User.hbm.xml not found
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:720) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Beta5.jar:4.0.0.Beta5]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2083) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Beta5.jar:4.0.0.Beta5]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2055) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Beta5.jar:4.0.0.Beta5]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2035) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Beta5.jar:4.0.0.Beta5]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1988) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Beta5.jar:4.0.0.Beta5]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1961) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Beta5.jar:4.0.0.Beta5]
      at com.mycompany.myapp.common.persistence.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:42) [classes:]
      at com.mycompany.myapp.common.businessobjects.ServerSettings.GetServerSettings(ServerSettings.java:216) [classes:]
      at com.mycompany.myapp.common.servlet.SecurityFilter.init(SecurityFilter.java:55) [classes:]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3245) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3836) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_26]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_26]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_26]


14:44:34,698 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myapp-maventest]] (MSC service thread 1-9) Exception starting filter EnterpriseSecurityFilter: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycompany.myapp.common.persistence.HibernateUtil
      at com.mycompany.myapp.common.businessobjects.ServerSettings.GetServerSettings(ServerSettings.java:224) [classes:]
      at com.mycompany.myapp.common.servlet.SecurityFilter.init(SecurityFilter.java:55) [classes:]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3245) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3836) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_26]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_26]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_26]


14:44:34,699 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myapp-maventest]] (MSC service thread 1-9) Exception starting filter CompanySecurityFilter: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycompany.myapp.common.persistence.HibernateUtil
      at com.mycompany.myapp.common.businessobjects.ServerSettings.GetServerSettings(ServerSettings.java:224) [classes:]
      at com.mycompany.myapp.common.servlet.SecurityFilter.init(SecurityFilter.java:55) [classes:]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3245) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3836) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_26]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_26]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_26]


14:44:34,701 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myapp-maventest]] (MSC service thread 1-9) Exception starting filter StationSecurityFilter: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycompany.myapp.common.persistence.HibernateUtil
      at com.mycompany.myapp.common.businessobjects.ServerSettings.GetServerSettings(ServerSettings.java:224) [classes:]
      at com.mycompany.myapp.common.servlet.SecurityFilter.init(SecurityFilter.java:55) [classes:]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3245) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3836) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_26]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_26]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_26]


14:44:34,702 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myapp-maventest]] (MSC service thread 1-9) Exception starting filter StudioSecurityFilter: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycompany.myapp.common.persistence.HibernateUtil
      at com.mycompany.myapp.common.businessobjects.ServerSettings.GetServerSettings(ServerSettings.java:224) [classes:]
      at com.mycompany.myapp.studio.StudioSecurityFilter.init(StudioSecurityFilter.java:46) [classes:]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3245) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3836) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_26]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_26]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_26]
```

Our project is structured like

```
Project
|
|-pom.xml
|
|-src
|  |-main
|     |-java
|     |   |-com... businessobjects
|     |-resources
|     |   |-META-INF
|     |-webapp
|
|-test
```

we have hibernate.cfg.xml in src/main/resources/META-INF, and various *.class and *hbm.xml in src/main/java/com/businessobjects/.  Our hibernate.cfg.xml looks like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="datasourceName">java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <mapping resource="com/mycompany/myapp/common/businessobjects/User.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/mycompany/myapp/common/businessobjects/Company.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/mycompany/myapp/common/businessobjects/ServerSettings.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/mycompany/myapp/common/businessobjects/Station.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I've tried different paths to point to the *hbm.xml files - none seem to work.  I've even tried giving it the absolute path to the *hbm.xml files, that didn't work either.

I've also tried copying the *hbm.xml into the same directory as hibernate.cfg.xml - that also didn't work, same error.

Looks like it errors out at this point in the code of my HibernateUtil class

```
static {
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        sessionFactory = configuration.configure(
            new File("/path/to/src/main/resources/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml")
            ).buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        log.error("Initial SessionFactory lookup failed.", ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

Any ideas what's going on?  Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Move your mapping files into src/main/resources. Only .java files belong in src/main/java.

**Edit:** I've set up an [example project on github](https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/hibernate-with-xml-mappings) showing how to correctly reference XML mapping files from a hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: I tried that, I also tried moving them to src/main/META-INF (same directory as my hibernate.cfg.xml) - same error.  I think something else is going on.

Comment: Updated my answer with a sample project. Check out the link.

Answer (score 3):

Maven only processes .java files from src/main/java, so putting the .hbm.xml files into that part of the tree means they won't end up in the war file.

Maven picks up config files from src/main/resources and as you've mapped the .hbm.xml files with a path, they would need to go into `src/main/resources/com/mycompany/myapp/common/businessobjects`.

Hope that helps.